# crossdomain cookie using iframe, how?

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-domain

I searched a lot on this topic, but didn't really found a solid answer
to this.

I need to set a cookie from any domain (out of my control),
lets say "**Domain B**" to my main domain, lets say "**Domain A**", and be able 
to read the cookie also, without exiting **Domain B**. kinda like Facebook
connect for websites, or Snap.com, and others of the sort. how it that done?

If I look at lets say http://ajaxian.com/ I see *Firecookie* shows cookies from many domains
being used on that website, and I really wanna know how it's achieved.

Comment: You can't set set cookies for other domains. The cookies you see on ajaxian.com are set by the specific site (facebook, ...) in their iframes. So those sites set the cookies themselves.

Comment: I can set cookie, that's easy. passing hash to iframe I create from Domain B, pointing to my domain, there it creates a cookie with that hash data...

Comment: I think this a a big clue to my problem :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Setting_a_cookie

Comment: can this be done without a receiver pager like Facebook does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way one normally sets a cookie on a 3rd party site is a webbug, a 1x1 pixel transparent gif served with a cookie or written with script to set domain b stuff to be read by domain a via a server

Comment: could you explain more please?